# How to increment the valueof the last span created with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, button, html-lists, addition, increment

I was looking for many solutions but I never (for now) found a solution.
I would like to increment the value of the last span created by a click in a created li tag which is of course inside of an unordered list.

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Add an Item">
<div id="cntn">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>Item<span class="listAdd">1</span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">2</span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">3</span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">4</span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">5</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the iQuery

```
$(document).on('click','#btn1', function() {
  $("#cntn ul").append('<li>Item <span class="listAdd"></span></li>');
  $('.listAdd').append(Number($('.listAdd').text())+ 1);
});
```

Basically, I would like to add a new list item with an incremented value in the span after clicking the button.
If you can help me that would be amazing, I'm super stuck... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/k57zecqd/

You're not defining which element to add too, so you're adding to them all. Define .last() to simply account for the last element of that type. From there, I went and got the last value of the elements, and added 1 to it - expecting it to be an integer in all cases.

After that, I then add the last item the value that's been calculated previously. Doing it sooner means that I'm adding 1 to NaN, which means I get no value for the position. Of note: the final line of code shouldn't be an append, as much as being something to insert into the element most likely, for sake of code completion and standards, but this will work and get you most of the way.

```
$(document).on('click','#btn1', function(){
var val = parseInt($('.listAdd').last().text())+1;
$("#cntn ul").append('<li>Item <span class="listAdd"></span></li>');
$('.listAdd').last().append(val);
});
```

Comment: Amazing, I was trying to add :last after the span class but I was not thinking about the issue in that way, Thank you so much Gyht !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method, depending on the purpose of the `<span>` elements is to avoid explicitly assigning numbers to them, and instead using CSS generated content:

```js
// caching a reference to the <button> element:
let button = document.querySelector('#btn1');

// binding the anonymous method of as the 'click' event-handler:
button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  // creating an <li> and a <span> element:
  let li = document.createElement('li'),
      span = document.createElement('span');

  // setting the text of the <li>:
  li.textContent = 'Item ';
  
  // appending the <span> to the <li>:
  li.appendChild(span);

  // adding the 'listAdd' class to the <span>:
  span.classList.add('listAdd');

  // finding the first (if any) 'ul.tabs' element, and appending
  // the <li> (along with its content) to that element:
  document.querySelector('ul.tabs').appendChild(li);
});
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  counter-reset: spanCount;
}

.tabs li {
  counter-increment: spanCount;
}

li span.listAdd::before {
  content: counter(spanCount);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Add an Item">
<div id="cntn">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd"></span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd"></span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd"></span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd"></span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Obviously the above could also be rewritten, if the `<span>` is purely to present/style the numbers, to apply the generated content to the `<li>` elements instead:

```js
// caching a reference to the <button> element:
let button = document.querySelector('#btn1');

// binding the anonymous method of as the 'click' event-handler:
button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  // creating an <li> and a <span> element:
  let li = document.createElement('li');

  // setting the text of the <li>:
  li.textContent = 'Item ';

  // finding the first (if any) 'ul.tabs' element, and appending
  // the <li> to that element:
  document.querySelector('ul.tabs').appendChild(li);
});
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  counter-reset: spanCount;
}

.tabs li {
  counter-increment: spanCount;
}

/* using ::after, instead of ::before, in order to
   correctly place the generated content: */
li::after {
  /* note the addition of an empty space to separate
     the counter from the text: */
  content: ' ' counter(spanCount);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Add an Item">
<div id="cntn">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS generated content is not present in the DOM, however, so if the user must be able to interact with the counter/number (selecting, copying etc) then the following is one option:

```js
// binding the anonymous function as the 'click' event-handler
// of the '#btn1' element:
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {

  // creating an <li> element:
  $('<li>', {
    // setting its text to the supplied string:
    'text': 'Item '

  // appending a new element to the created <li>:
  }).append(

    // creating a <span> element:
    $('<span>', {

      // setting its class:
      'class': 'listAdd',

      // setting the text of the <span> to be equal to
      // the current number of '.listAdd' elements, plus 1:
      'text': $('.listAdd').length + 1
    })

  // appending the created <li> - along with its created child -
  // to the '.tabs' element:
  ).appendTo('.tabs');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Add an Item">
<div id="cntn">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">1</span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">2</span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">3</span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">4</span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">5</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The above can, of course, be rewritten with plain JavaScript:

```js
// finding the first (if any) '#btn1' element:
document.querySelector('#btn1')

  // binding the anonymous function as the event-handler of
  // the 'click' event:
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
  
    // creating an <li> element and a <span> element:
    let li = document.createElement('li'),
        span = document.createElement('span'),
    // finding the first (if any) element matching the CSS Selector:
        list = document.querySelector('.tabs');

    // setting the text content of the <li> element:
    li.textContent = 'Item ';
    // appending the <span> element to the <li> element:
    li.appendChild(span);

    // adding the 'listAdd' class ot the created <span>:
    span.classList.add('listAdd');
    
    // setting the text content of the created <span> to be equal to
    // the current number of 'span.listAdd' elements found within the
    // list element, and adding 1 to that number:
    span.textContent = list.querySelectorAll('span.listAdd').length + 1;

    // appending the created <li> (and children) to the list element:
    list.appendChild(li);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Add an Item">
<div id="cntn">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">1</span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">2</span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">3</span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">4</span></li>
    <li>Item <span class="listAdd">5</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

- CSS:

  - [CSS Generated content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).
  - [CSS pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).
  - [Using CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
  - [`NodeList.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/length).
- jQuery:

  - [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append).
  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).